# Convert array objects to string and separate the values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, multidimensional-array

I have the following result

```
Array ( 
      [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Identification ) 
      [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Assay ) 
      [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => pH(Acidity/Alkalinity)) 
      [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Sterility )
    )
```

What i want is to separate the object array values using a comma and return as a string,
so as to have this result:

```
 Identification, Assay, ph(Acid/Alkalinity), Sterility
```

I have tried the following

```
$data=(array)$result;
$answer=implode(",",$data);
```

This return :

```
Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

How best can this be achieved?

Comment: what is the problem when using `$result[0]->name` ? you must use `foreach` to iterate the `objects` inside the `array`

Comment: I want to get all the values not just the first one in the array index

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are missing the fact that you are dealing with an array of objects.

Looks like you can achieve that by doing:

```
$output = array_map(function ($object) { return $object->name; }, $input);
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

Comment: Just for anyone curious, you leave the two $objects as they are named. Change $object->name to $object->name_of_my_field, and $input to be the name of your array of objects. 
And then it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To use this feature in the 'title' attribute I did:

```
echo implode('&NewLine;', $output);
```

Answer (score -1):

It will convert the array of objects to a string, and you can store it in the database, use

`serialize(array_of_object)`

Might help someone. I used it in my case. Thank you!